# Reordering Matrix Rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows

I have a 6 x 8 matrix in matlab and would like to reorder the rows. Is there an easy way for me to shift around specific rows?

For my purposes, I would like to take initial rows 1, 2, and 3, and reorder them as rows 4, 5, and 6. Initial row 4 should be row 2, row 5 should be row 3, and row 6 should be row 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
M = rand(6,8);

new_row_order = [6;4;5;1;2;3];  

M_new = M(new_row_order, :);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can index the original matrix in the following way:

```
 P = A([6 4 5], :)
```

Where `A` is the original matrix and `P` is the permuted matrix.

This means that the rows of P will be the 6th row of A, the 4th row of A and finally the 5th row of A.